# SP 2010 Multilevel SPCascadeDropdowns not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, spcascadedropdowns

I have a problem with an Multilevel  Dropdown Cascade .

I have on List where the user should work with "Projects"

[image]

and 3 Lists for the cascades

[image]

The first cascade works fine but not the second
[image]

this is the Java script I use

[image]

I do not see the mistake, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that it might be related to how you named the lists and columns. SharePoint does not handle underscores or dots very well. I suggest using F12 to check the console what errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here are articles about three level Cascading dropdown in SharePoint 2010 for your reference:

http://ratikantas.blogspot.com/2012/09/cascading-dropdown-upto-3-level-in.html

http://microsoftsharepointdevelopment2010.blogspot.com/2013/01/working-with-cascading-dropdown-in.html